# SONAR mojo fails to download jdbc/findebugs

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have been using sonar on my local machine for a long time but at one point it just snapped and started failing. Following build error have been spat out by sonar maven mojo:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Can not execute Sonar

Embedded error: Fail to download the file: http://192.168.212.197:9000/deploy/plugins/findbugs/sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.2.1.jar (no proxy)
Read timed out
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

or

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Can not execute Sonar

Embedded error: Fail to download the file: http://192.168.212.197:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.jar (no proxy)
Read timed out
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried fiddling with sonar configurations by changing default host - tried my local IP tried 'localhost' tried my domain name but it just says it can't download either jdbc-driver.jar either findbugs-plugin-3.2.1.jar. When I enter URL into a web browser I instantly fetch any of those two jars, which I think indicates that they are available for grabbing once sonar app is up and running, and I can successfully find those jars in sonar web app deploy folder.

Also I am using MySQL 5.1, even tried it with default out of the box DERBY DB. Read quite few articles on similar topics but there was some configuration problems within poms or elsewhere. This is different and I just can't put my finger on the problem. Case in point it used to work and one day it stopped, maybe this is some network problems ?

Has anyone have any ideas on this one ?

Comment: What puzzles me is how you have two errors... Are these from two different builds? Secondly you've stated that Sonar was stable, are you saying nothing has been changed? All this would suggest an intermittent networking issue between your build and the Sonar server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the root cause of this problem. As I forgot to mentioned am running sonar on windows 7 and this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2735855 update was causing troubles. I removed it and everything seems back on track.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Sonar are you running? It looks like the following issue, fixed by version 2.5:

- [SONAR-2016](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2016)